# MS-Graph read tasks with admin consent

Tags: .net-core, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to read the Planner task for the users of my tenant. So I configured admin consent for "Tasks.Read", "Tasks.Read.Shared", "Groups.Read.All", "Groups.ReadWrite.All" for the app that is doing that. 
Like mentioned here: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/graph/api/planneruser-list-tasks?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http
I desined my code to get a token like mentioned here: https://briantjackett.com/2018/12/13/introduction-to-calling-microsoft-graph-from-a-c-net-core-application/
I get a token back and it is valid. (Checked with baerer token check tool.)
I thought that I could access the tasks from the Graph API like '/v1.0/users/{userId}/planner/tasks' but I get HTTP 401 back.
Can anyone give me the missing link? Thanks a lot.

```
_appId = configuration.GetValue<string>("AppId");
_tenantId = configuration.GetValue<string>("TenantId");
_clientSecret = configuration.GetValue<string>("ClientSecret");
_clientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
     .Create(_appId)
     .WithTenantId(_tenantId)
     .WithClientSecret(_clientSecret)
     .Build();
var graphClient = GraphClientFactory.Create(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(Authenticate));
var result = await graphClient.GetAsync($"/v1.0/users/{userId}/planner/tasks")

public async Task<string> GetTokenAsync()
{
    AuthenticationResult authResult = await _clientApplication.AcquireTokenForClient(_scopes)
        .ExecuteAsync();
    return authResult.AccessToken;
}

private async Task Authenticate(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    var token = await GetTokenAsync();
    request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", token);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading tasks for other users is currently not allowed. A user can only read their assigned tasks. As an alternative, you can read the tasks in specific Plans, and sort out the users from that data, if you want to collect assignments from a set of Plans. You can provide feedback on this behavior in [Planner UserVoice](https://planner.uservoice.com/forums/330525-microsoft-planner-feedback-forum) with the description of what you are trying to accomplish.

Additionally, application permissions are supported now, if that works for your scenario.

Comment: Runnig over all task did it, but its not a very optimal solution because of the used resources to do so.

Answer (score 0):

`/v1.0/users/{userId}/planner/tasks` is for [getting tasks via getting a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), and you will need User permissions (`User.Read.All`) to get tasks via that call.

(Also Do you really need `Groups.ReadWrite.All`? Are you making changes to groups? -- it's not in your original description)

Comment: Giving the app the 'User.Read.All' doesn't change anything. You are right I do not need it at all.